Is there a way to provide AsyncPoco with a CancellationToken?
Most Async APIs have a way to provide a CancellationToken.
But I could not find it.
Methods should have overloads that accept CancellationTokens.
(Or should they?)
IDatabase //Does not contain anything

Internally it seams that the lib uses Cancellation.None.

Related: Stopping a task without a CancellationToken and also How to cancel a Task in await?
